# How can I prevent my app from showing in Android Market on tablets?

Tags: android, google-play

How can I prevent my app from showing in Android Market on large and xlarge screens (tablets)?

Comment: you can define device classes in the android market if you upload the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this documentation: [Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html), specifically section named [Declaring an App is Only for Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps):

Answer (score 1):

In your android manifest you need to add a stanza like this:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work, see the "Caution" part here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps